# How can I forward all pages on a domain to a hash on the index page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, cloudflare, serverless

I'm making a serverless url forwarding service, implemented only in HTML/CSS/JS, with JQuery and Ajax.

Right now, I'm forwarding `example.com#slug` to a long url, but I'd like `example.com/slug` to do the same. How can I forward every `/<something>` to `#<something>`, using either Cloudflare or javascript?

Edit:
This is the code for the redirect

```
// Redirect
if (window.location.hash != "") {
    $.getJSON(endpoint + "/" + window.location.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase(), function(data) {
        data = data["result"];
        if (data != null) { // Redirect
            window.location.href = data;
        } else { // Show page
            document.getElementById("page").style.display = "inline";
        }
    });
} else { // Show page
    document.getElementById("page").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Edit 2: I'm keeping this serverless, so the code above is being called directly from index.html. I do have use of Cloudflare workers, so that can be a part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

capture the url before forwarding, parse the path, construct desired url, continue with the forwarding process

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the url before forwarding"?

Comment: interject request

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: i disagree with your opinion

Comment: What do you mean by "interject request"?

Comment: By that I meant that you could have your custom logic execute during handling of `/slug` and have it route/redirect to `#slug`>

Comment: How do I "have my custom logic execute during handling of /slug"?

Comment: Well, when your service receives /slug, redirect to /#slug. You said you're authoring that service, correct? What am I not understandng here?

Comment: Well my service only executes on index.html, regarding different #s. How do redirect all the /s?

Comment: can you show any code? maybe simplified. It's hard to keep guessing.

Comment: ok, so, this looks like a javascript designed to run on the client - correct? Do you have control over the server-side code that delivers the script that you added to the OP (which in turn sets window.location)?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more specific. I'm keeping this client-side only. The only server stuff will be through cloudflare workers.

Comment: So that script isn't delivered, it's directly called from index.html